# vtigercrm target _blank is not working

Tags: php, html, vtiger

I am facing target _blank in the vtiger crm html editor in the Documents module. When I add a description with external link with target _blank in the documents description,when I click  on the link.It is open in the same window , The target _blank property is not working. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you provide that Link which you are adding in Document? So i can check what is wrong with your Link or code. You have to Provide that what you have tried. Based on that we can give and reply our answer.

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">&nbsp;Test</a></p>
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `target="_new"` also. This is also works same as `target="_blank"`